# Automated Build Host Agent

Tags: c#, tfs, build, asp.net-core, openiddict

I have a solution with a single asp.net core console application. It builds locally and on a hosted agent on TFS. 
I want to use a project ([OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)) on GitHub, downloaded it and added it to my solution. I created a NuGet.Config file, which is necessary for OpenIddict. It builds fine locally, but the dependencies for OpenIddict (for example: AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Extensions) cannot be resolved, when built on a hosted agent.

Background:
I am very new to automated builds and only using the available online tools without installing tfs on a machine. I tried different build definitions but none succeeded. Feel free to ask for more specific information, since I am not sure what is relevant.

Comment: Did you get any related  error info in the build log?

Answer (score 0):

If you can build successful in your local environment. First, you must make sure the environment on your build sever(build agent) are as same as your local. This will greatly reduce the risk of build failures.

According to the dependencies error, seems the issue more related to the environment on build agent. And if you have create a Nuget. Config file, make sure add a [Nuget install task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer) in your build definition before the build to restore the packages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I think the problem has something to do with the build environment of the agent. I have the Nuget Install step and set the link to the NuGet.Config file. I didn't installed anything else on my local machine as far as I know. How can you customize a hosted agent or see details regarding the setup? Edit extra info: I am trying a gated check in

Comment: You have said it builds on a hosted agent on TFS. The agent should installed on a local or remote machine. You can try to build manually on the build agent ( machine) **not through tfs** to narrow down the issue whether related to agent environment or the TFS build definition settings.

Comment: I just installed an agent on my local machine and it builds without those errors. But it still fails on the hosted agent, due to the dependency error. The package is on the MyGet feed, configured in the NuGet.Config file.